# In Sesame, how does one derive RDFS/OWL materialization results that have an RDF literal in the subject position?

Tags: rdf, owl, sesame, rdfs

I have a problem with RDFS entailment in [Sesame 2.8.5](http://rdf4j.org/). I want to automatically deduce (3) from (1) and (2) (using [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) notation here). This is defined as rule **rdfs3** in [the RDF 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) and as rule **prp-rng** in [the OWL-RL specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rif-owl-rl/).

```
(1) foaf:givenName rdfs:range     xsd:string .
(2) ex:wouter      foaf:givenName "Wouter"   .
(3) "Wouter"       a              xsd:string .
```

I have implemented this in Sesame using the `ForwardChainingRDFSInferencer` class as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RepositoryException, RDFHandlerException {
  Repository r = new SailRepository(new ForwardChainingRDFSInferencer(new MemoryStore()));
  r.initialize();
  ValueFactory f = r.getValueFactory();
  RepositoryConnection c = r.getConnection();
  try {
    c.add(FOAF.GIVEN_NAME, RDFS.RANGE, XMLSchema.STRING);
    c.add(f.createURI("http://example.org/", "wouter"), FOAF.GIVEN_NAME, f.createLiteral("Wouter", XMLSchema.STRING));
    RepositoryResult<Statement> s = c.getStatements(null, null, null, true);
    Rio.write(Iterations.addAll(s, new LinkedHashModel()), System.out, RDFFormat.TURTLE);
  } finally {c.close();}
}
```

The output contains many inferred facts such as (4) but does not include fact (3).

```
(4) ex:wouter a rdfs:Resource .
```

My question is: If fact 3 is not derived because a literal is not allowed to appear in the subject position of an RDF triple, then how it it possible to perform full RDFS and/or OWL materialization (in line with the above mentioned specifications) in Sesame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literals are not allowed in subject positions in RDF. Therefore, fact 3 would not be a legal RDF triple, and therefore Sesame's inferencer does not derive it. This does not mean that Sesame's inferencer is incomplete: it derives all RDFS-entailed facts that can be legally derived. Or if you wish to argue that this does constitute incompleteness, then that means that any RDF reasoner implementing RDFS Entailment is *by definition* incomplete, as it will not be able to derive such facts within the RDF standard.

Note that the RDF Semantics spec explicitly refers to a notion of "generalized RDF" when discussing the possibility of having literals in subject positions (and making the type of entailments you want) - however this notion is itself a hypothetical extension of the standard, and not itself normative.

So, long story short: if you want literals in subject positions, you are not doing RDF, and you can't use Sesame (or any other standards-compliant RDF framework).

Comment: My question is now clarified / made explicit: how to perform full (i.e., including rules **rdfs3** and **prp-rng**) RDFS and/or OWL materialization in Sesame?